# Bootstrap Alert - HTML Inside of it

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm using Laravel & Bootstrap, to create success / error messages.

In my Laravel Controller, I return the following :

```
return redirect()->back()
                 ->with('error', 'Account Not Found - Please Try Again with Correct Email Address, Otherwise  Please <a href="#">Signup</a>');
```

The problem I have, Is that when I return back to my view, The full error string appears as text.

[image: Message String]

Is their a parameter or setting I can put in my JavaScript to allow it to be output as html?

Thanks

Comment: Before output error, try to use: htmlspecialchars_decode on a string -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with bootstrap it is showing it correctly but laravel treats it as plain text and not as html. When you echo the error add the link in the view after `{{$error}} <a href="#">Signup</a>'` and remove the link from error.

Comment: Great, Just realised you can do a blade output as html :

 <p>{!! session('error') !!}</p>